# CSS Grid (or flexbox?) with 1 row and 3 columns, but 2-3 elements that the 1st element will span 1-2 columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying my darndest to accomplish this relatively simple layout for 2-3 elements. Everything I've tried from `px/fr/%` with `minmax()` & grid can't seem to get it quite right.

I want my `input` to take up all remaining space leftover whether or not the `button` is present. The `select` should remain the same size regardless if `button` is present.

The percentages make most sense, but isn't exactly working like I'd like.
no button: 75% input + 25% select
with button: 50% input + 25% select + 25% button

What am I missing on getting this to work? Am I just thinking about this wrong? SHOW ME THE WAY!

I've even tried adding independent css to each element with the `grid-column: 1 / 3`:

```
.input-grid .input-grid-input { grid-column: 1 / 3 }
.input-grid .input-grid-select { grid-column: 4 }
.input-grid .input-grid-button { grid-column: 5 }
```

With out button:

[image: how I want it to look with no button]

With button:

[image: how I want it to look with a button]

```css
.input-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(50%, 75%) 25% minmax(0, 25%);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-grid">
  <input type="text" class="input-grid-input" value="input" data-form-type="other">

  <select class="input-grid-select" data-form-type="other">
    <option value="Select Value 1">Select Value 1</option>
    <option value="Select Value 2" disabled="disabled">Select Value 2</option>
  </select>

  <button class="btn input-grid-btn btn--primary" hidden="hidden">
    Check Availability
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that specifying the third value of `grid-template-columns` (for the button) as `max-content`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. 

`grid-template-columns: minmax(50%, 75%) 25% max-content;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish what you want using flexbox. The elements within the *.grid* class will fill 100% of the space. In the instance you wanted them to appear on separate lines for smaller screens, you could just use a media query to *flex-wrap* elements.

**CSS**

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
}

.grid input {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

input[type = button] {
    display: block;
    text - align: center;
    max - width: 150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="grid">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input text">
    <select><option>Choose option</option></select>
    <input type="button" value="Check Availability">
</div>
```